# Word 2010 + Save math equation as image

Tags: ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

how can I save a math equation (from a word document) as an image, using c#?? Perhaps, I should use openxml sdk ? Anyone can help?

Comment: you can't in Open XML or the SDK. you'd probably have to use Interop for this.

Answer (score 2):

Save the document as Word 97-2000 (i.e. .doc instead of .docx) then save the document as a webpage. All equations will be saved as image in the for_img directory.