# Enter MS-Word equations into text area

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, ms-word

I am creating a web application where teachers can enter maths, physics and chemistry questions and notes. The problem that I am currently facing is how to enable copying equations from Microsoft Word and being able to paste into a textarea. Non-equation parts of text successfully copy over. Alternatively, is there is a way a teacher can upload a Word file and my application converts it to an image?

For directly typing into the textarea, I am using wiris editor. I am using PHP, MySQL and JavaScript.

Comment: Have the teachers use a screen snipping tool, and save the snip as a picture.  Then it can be uploaded.

Comment: @SableFoste Is there way to copy and  paste microsoft equation to textarea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no. The best solution for you would be for teachers to export equations as images. It appears that [Word 2010 + Save math equation as image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533984/word-2010-save-math-equation-as-image) has a solution for this (cumbersome as it is).

From this image, your page would have to accept image files for upload. You can prepare this by having your form include an enctype as follows:

```
<form action="save.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="image" />
</form>
```

Comment: As reputation has just now gone below 15 points so cant vote 4 u but thanks

Answer (score 1):

Copying images to clipboard won't work. You must use fileupload control to upload image files....

Comment: Is there a way to copy and paste from microsoft word without loosing special characters or formating .

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called "**Moodle**". In that, you can upload the Questions from Word Document. It accepts even Math Equation. And Quiz can be attempted in Moodle Module. And You can export the Questions as Word Document.

For Importing and Exporting, you need to install a Plugin called "wordtable". You can get this plugin in Moodle plugin list.